# prevent scrolling from iframe but still clickable javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Is it possible to use the parent scroll when I start the scroll from the embedded iframe? Currently I'm using `pointer-event: none` but the embedded iframe prevents clickable events. I tried also manipulate other events like `touchmove` but I failed. Feel free to answer and thank you in advance!

Comment: No, it's not possible to scroll the parent page from an iframe. Prevent iframe scrolling and set the height of the iframe to its maximum content, then you can scroll the main page and the iframe is scrolled too.

Comment: nope you can't preventDeflaut onScroll event. you can back to initial position after scroll move but this is ackward. Removing scroll bars when you are over  iframe is not best as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to scroll the parent page from an iframe. However, you could consider using `embed` instead of `iframe`. This will give you more control over how scroll works.